# How to find corners of square from its center point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

It's has been a while since I used any basic trigonometry, so I'm here requesting some aiding. I have the center point of a square (as lng/lat pair which I believe I can use as x/y) and the side length, and I need to find all 4 corners coordinates from this origin.

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: Does the square require an orientation?  The simplest answer is simply the four points (+/- 1/2 length +/- x, +/- 1/2 length +/-  y)

Comment: It doesn't require any orientation. It should be as simple as possible. Could you please elaborate you simplest answer? I am not that good with math...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the length of the square is L, I hope the drawing below answers your question. I called the center point c, and each corner p1,p2,p3 and p4.

[image]

Comment: Nice drawing...

Comment: Thanks for the input, even I could follow it. One more question, is there a way I can correctly convert lng/lat to x/y?

Comment: @dambros, sorry I don't know about this.

Comment: @fleablood, thx.

Answer (score 4):

In case the square is rotated around the center by an angle theta, w.r.t the ground position (considered as when the sides are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axis), the vertices are given as -

Let $L =$ length of the side. Let $(h,k)$ be the center point.

$(h -  \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta + \cos\theta), k - \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta - \cos\theta))$,
$(h +  \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta - \cos\theta), k - \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta + \cos\theta))$,
$(h +  \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta + \cos\theta), k + \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta - \cos\theta))$,
$(h -  \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta - \cos\theta), k + \frac{1}{2}L(\sin\theta + \cos\theta))$

Please beware, the answer provided by @fleablood seems to be wrong. It Didn't work out for me. It fails in the very basic case of $\theta=0^\circ$ and $\theta=90^\circ$. Or I'm misinterpreting the answer provided.

Comment: Thanks your answer works correctly. As you say the above answer fails for θ=0  and θ=90∘

Answer (score 2):

Let L = length of side.  Let (h,k) be the center point.

The simplest answer is $(h + \frac 1 2 L, k + \frac 1 2 L), (h + \frac 1 2 L, k - \frac 1 2 L),(h - \frac 1 2 L, k - \frac 1 2 L), (h - \frac 1 2 L, k + \frac 1 2 L)$

If the square must be rotated by the angle $\theta$, The the solutions are $(h + \frac 1 2 L \sin \theta, k + \frac 1 2 L \cos \theta), (h - \frac 1 2 L \cos \theta, k + \frac 1 2 L \sin \theta),(h - \frac 1 2 L \sin \theta, k - \frac 1 2 L \cos \theta), (h + \frac 1 2 L \cos \theta, k - \frac 1 2 L \sin \theta)$