# Finding the vertices of a regular pentagon centred around 0,0

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to preface this question by saying that I'm not the best at maths.

[Thanks to another post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3168029), I was able to find the corners of a rotated square centred on 0,0. Now however, I need to be able to find the vertices of a regular pentagon where the length of each side and the rotation of the pentagon are variable.

I was able to get basic equations for each coordinate, as follows (where L = side length):

$c_1 = L\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)$
$c_2 = L\cos\left(\frac \pi5\right)$
$s_1 = L\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)$
$s_2 = L\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)$

$P_1 = (0, L)$
$P_2 = (s_1, c_1)$
$P_3 = (s_2, -c_2)$
$P_4 = (-s_2, -c_2)$
$P_5 = (-s_1, c_1)$

How would I factor in rotation of the pentagon into this?

Comment: If your angle of rotation is $\theta$, then set $c_1 = L\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5} + \theta \right)$ and so on.

Comment: @StevenAlexisGregory I appreciate the response, however that doesn't seem to work, or I've possibly misunderstood. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uoidt99cmb

Comment: You also need to rotate $(0, L)$ to $L(cos \theta, sin \theta)$.

Comment: @liam-milbel do you know complex numbers?

Comment: @StevenAlexisGregory Yeah, I forgot to put that in before sharing the link. It's still only correct when the rotation is 0 though.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Honestly, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list of coordinates explicitly makes use of horizontal symmetry by using pairs of points with the same y coordinates and x coordinates of opposite signs. That symmetry obviously breaks down when you have a rotated pentagon. Instead you need to calculate each point separately as follows:

$$P_1 = (L\cos(0\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta), L\sin(0\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta))\\
P_2 = (L\cos(1\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta), L\sin(1\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta))\\
P_3 = (L\cos(2\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta), L\sin(2\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta))\\
P_4 = (L\cos(3\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta), L\sin(3\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta))\\
P_5 = (L\cos(4\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta), L\sin(4\cdot\frac{2\pi}5+\theta))$$

Note that I used the more traditional formulation with the $\cos$ in the x coordinate. You may want to swap the sines and cosines, which has the bonus of making $\theta$ rotate clockwise, and $\theta=0$ being the orientation with a horizontal base.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect for my needs. I had desired to go beyond 5 sides but had limited to 5 as I had perceived it to be too much work, but this just works for any number of sides. I did have to change $L$ in the equation to $\frac{L}{\sqrt 5}$ though.